# oracle value 99999999 getting rounded

Tags: oracle

I created the below table:

```
create table ex_employee (id number(20,4));
```

Then I have insert the below values:

```
insert into ex_employee values (9999999999999999.9999);
commit;
```

The result is being rounded up;

```
10000000000000000.0000
```

[In this link](https://community.oracle.com/thread/2330051) they explained if the precision execeeded then it will round up.

what should I do to keep the value not get rounded: 
9999999999999999.9999

Comment: @Amadan I tried it and still causing problem

Comment: I'm a little confused: 1. Testing against Oracle 11g your code works as aspected ( nothing is rounded). 2. Enlarging the inserted number results as aspected in `ORA-01438: value larger than specified precision allowed for this column`.

Comment: I think, it's just a display problem. See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/bb5f8/4

Comment: @evilive mind is 11g also , I dont know why its giving me such result , if you need any information or query ill provide to you.

Comment: @DirkNM so I didnt understand ? is it normal ? If i insert it in my application it will give 99999999999.9999 result ?

Comment: DISPLAY from database and STORING into database are different. You got a display issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The result is being rounded up [to] `10000000000000000.0000`
>
> what should I do to keep the value not get rounded: `9999999999999999.9999`

As you noticed yourself, this is a display problem, as your `NUMBER(20,4)` has sufficient significant digits to precisely represent that base10 number.

If addition to Lalit's answer concerning "display format", a common source for that behavior is to use an IEEE 754 float/double values at application-level to read back those numbers (resp. 7 / 15 significant *decimal* digits only). In addition, all decimal digits cannot be accurately represented using binary representation.

If your host language has support for that, you should "long decimal numbers". For example, Java has [BigDecimal](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html). Python has [Decimal](https://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html).

Answer (score 1):

Just set the **numformat** properly. In `SQL*Plus`, you could do it as `set numformat`.

```
SQL> set numformat 9999999999999999.9999
SQL> create table ex_employee (id number(20,4));

Table created.

SQL> insert into ex_employee values (9999999999999999.9999);

1 row created.

SQL> select id from ex_employee;

                    ID
----------------------
 9999999999999999.9999

SQL>
```